# Can SQL Server Management Studio edit column with prepopulated data by foreign key?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have two simple table with foreign key relationship.

I have a person how should edit this table. It is with common types, but he can't do it with foreign columns.

How I can make easy for edit this column?

In mysql editors were dropdown with list of items.

p.s he shouldn't work with primary keys. Only with some display name

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the select down to a single table it seems to always work. 
So that implies you have to tweak your where clause to not use joins for the main select statement.  You have to put the join in a sub select effectively. 
Something like this.

```
SELECT t.FldPkForTargetTbl
     , t.Fld1 
     , t.Fld2 
  FROM TargetTbl t 
 WHERE t.FldPkForTargetTbl IN ( SELECT a1.FldPkForTargetTbl 
                                  FROM TargetTbl a1 
                                 INNER JOIN OtherTbl o2 on o2.FldFKOnOtherTbl = a1.FldPkForTargetTbl
                                 WHERE o2.OtherCriteria = 42 )
```

*On background only for those that never use this feature.*  You can see the sql query that is used to pull up the direct edit window by using the below button.  This would be if you right clicked and did an "Edit Top 200 Rows" action.

[image]

Comment: Hard way. I need some yesy solution

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to :

1. remove the relationship between those to tables.
2. remove identity from the primary column in the first table.
3. update value.
4. recreate relationship between tables again.
5. reactivate the identity property.

**See this :**

- [Remove Relationship between Tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189579.aspx).
- [How to remove identity property](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/03/sql-server-add-or-remove-identity-property-on-column/) .